# WIFI not always working - Shuttle XS35

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, shuttle

I have a little headless audio server runing LUbuntu.  It always had the occasional wifi problem -- seemingly not able to connect.  Usually I would reboot the system and the problem would go away.   With the upgrade to LUbuntu 19.10, the problem seems to be more persistent.  Maybe 1 out of 2 reboots the WIFI will not work.

Here is the output of wireless-info when the wifi is connected.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wQnckTYmyw/

Any idea what might be causing this intermittent wifi?  If the wifi is up, it stays up.  If the machine boots and the wifi is down, there appears to be nothing I can do to get it to connect, other than a reboot.

Perhaps this is relevant: I have my wifi router assign a static IP address to this machine.  Perhaps I need to tell the machine that?

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3** output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Holco Enterprise Co, Ltd/Shuttle Computer I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1297:4034]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

**rfkill list** output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the wireless device?

Comment: @Pilot6, wlp1s0 is the device name on ifconfig.

Comment: The name gives no information. Is it a PCI or USB device?

Comment: @Pilot6: it's the JMC261, a PCI Express device.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, appended.